# ZoneAwarePromise overwritten when adding Handsontable to Angular-CLI scripts

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, handsontable, zone.js

I'd like to add the Handsontable library to my Angular project. Using [angular-cli](/questions/tagged/angular-cli), I added Handsontable to the scripts section of `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js"
]
```

Webpack compiles successfully, however when loading the web application, I'm encountering the following error:

```
VM473:34309 Unhandled promise rejection Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
    at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.assertZonePatched (zone.js:44)
    at new NgZone (core.es5.js:3757)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (core.es5.js:4551)
    at core.es5.js:4596
    at run (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:34279:22)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:34292:28)
    at MutationObserver.flush (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:91358:9)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:154)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (zone.js:132)
```

Apparently, [zone.js](/questions/tagged/zone.js) (imported in `polyfills.ts` by default) is loaded before Handsontable (actually the polyfills bundle [is loaded first](https://angular.io/guide/webpack#polyfills)). I found a possible workaround by copying the JS file to my asset folder and moving the Handsontable import to the `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="assets/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  </head>
// ...
```

However, this does feel like a hack, as there is a scripts section in `.angular-cli.json` for the purpose of using it.

Any idea on how to fix this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: where you're importing zone.js? using any kind of loader?

Comment: @MehulJoshi, as descriped above, zone.js is imported in polyfills.ts (which is loaded first).

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, i've moved "import 'zone.js/dist/zone'" from "polyfill.ts" into "main.ts"

Comment: Are there any potential downsides of moving it into main.ts?

Comment: This really feels hacky. Is there really no better explanation for why this happens? There aren't any issues on GitHub or anything regarding this and they don't mention it in their docs, so there must be another factor.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the newest version of `zone.js`, the error will just gone.