# Multiple angular application issue in IE browser due to pollyfill.js loaded separately for each application

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular9

My Problem:

I am having an angular application which is part of larger CMS system embedded in iframe, there i have another angular application already hosted in header part of CMS.
I am facing an issue in Internet explorer for zone.js as pollyfill.js file is loading two times one for each application.

Assumption:
My assumption is that as header angular application loads its pollyfill then my second application load its pollyfill.js and it throws error as :

**Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)**

Please suggest an approach to deal with this situation or route me to correct article if already exist somewhere as i have not found relevant solution yet

What i tried so far:
I have tried solution of using/creating custom webpack angular builders instead of default angular devkit builders referring one of an article but still not succeed.
also have two different app root name for these application.

[image]

your help highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Angualr and zone.js are you using? I found some similar threads and you can refer to them. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305424/unhandled-promise-rejection-windowglobal-promise-has-been-overwritten) says the error can be fixed by using zone.js 0.8.19. You can have a try or try the newest version of zone.js. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566898/zoneawarepromise-overwritten-when-adding-handsontable-to-angular-cli-scripts) says it can be solved by moving `import 'zone.js/dist/zone'` from "polyfill.ts" into "main.ts".

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't worked. can you please suggest something else @YuZhou